# What is function(work) of header in c programming?

Tags: c

what header line actually do in c programming?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

this code gives same output with or without header line, why it is so?

Comment: Headers make function prototypes available / known to the compiler. Try using `strlen` without including `string.h`. Please find a C tutorial or textbook.

Comment: Without the header included, wth MSVC I get a compiler warning that it does not know what `printf` means, and then a linker error. So it doesn't work at all.

Comment: If you can get that code to run without the include line, then read the warnings you get while doing that.

Comment: Without the header the program is invalid. If your compiler didn't tell you that, you need a newer compiler.

Comment: @n.m. that is not true, the header definition is a compatibility thing, it will fail if your environment doesn't have the libraries in the expected places though. Of course, if you want custom libs you gotta use them, and it is a good practice to always put them, this because there are macros and types that are not available if the declaration is not done.

Comment: @Marco You are unfortunately  wrong. Every function or variable needs to be declared before use. Please read the C standard or a good *modern* C book. In historic versions of C one could omit declarations of some functions, but priintf is not one if them.

Comment: @n.m. I am totally ok with putting headers, that is the best way to do it, but, the compiler should search on the standard paths in order to find what it needs. The event will be a warning, and the compilation should finish without issues.

Comment: @Marco "warning, and the compilation should finish without issues". A warning **is** an issue. In C++11 the program is **invalid**, as in not allowed by the standard. In earlier versions, it has **undefined behaviour**.

Comment: @n.m. You are talking about C11. I haven't checked that yet, I am on C90 and those warnings can be avoided without issues. Now, note that even in C11, the lack of the prototypes is no a big issue, they added as a constraint for probably... best practices and performance?! I don't know

Comment: @Marco C90 is a historic standard that was supplanted 20 years ago. Even in C90 calling printf without a prototype in scope is **undefined behaviour**. Headers are not "best practice", they are the only valid practice. "the lack of the prototypes is no a big issue" Have you *read* C11? I have. It is illegal to call a function without an explicit declaration in scope.

Comment: @n.m. Mine is C99..., I can run all the ones prior to C11. No, I haven't read that one, the linux servers that we have are all with gcc that don't support C11, so.. I am not touching them. Now, for the sake of this particular question!!, why it happened? why it was working?! It was explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The headers are just defining the prototypes, not importing anything, in C you are not actually importing the functions, etc.

When you use printf, you are just calling the standard lib libc.so (if working on linux), which will anyways print the string.

IF, you don't have an standard function, you need to declare it in the header, that definition will then be taken from your file.

Now, as a matter of compatibility, you should put it, since there are libary declarations that are only going to get added when the header is in place, like specific types and macros.

I am leaving here the libc manual, so you can take a look:
https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/pdf/libc.pdf

Another thing to take into account is performance, the lack of macros will make your program suffer (not in your case), but in a real big program, and those are not going to be in your program if the include is not in place, so .. it is always good practice to put them.

Update: Note that this is not C11 compliant, the code will work on any implementation preC11 standard. (thanks @n.m here for the note)

Answer (score -1):

Ok header file is like you know like library every thing is defined in header file befor you code.  every thing are stored in header.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This answer is not really correct. It is not recommended to put definitions into headers. In vast majority of cases only declarations should go in headers.